# Upload a picture to the div using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

There is such code, displays a picture in a div with a class "img", but works not correctly, prompt the decision

```
<div class="other"><a href="/index1.html">Link1</a></div>
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="other"><a href="/index2.html">Link2</a></div>
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="other"><a href="/index3.html">Link3</a></div>
<div class="img"></div>
```

index.html such

```
<div class="avat"><img src="/ava.jpg"></div>
```

Script

```
$('.other a').each(function(){
var PostURL = this.href;
var gtag = $(this).next().load(PostURL + ' .avat img');
$('.img').html(gtag);
});
```

Comment: What is purpose of `$('.img').html(gtag);`?

Comment: and i think `$('.img').html(gtag);` are wrong here because athor maybe wanted to update each img tag in a loop so you should use callback that `load` method provides

Comment: Load the image into the variable gtag and then output it to the div, or how correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
$('.img').html(gtag);
```

which sets `.innerHTML` of `.img` elements to `.next()` element.

Also, the selector should be `$(this).parent().next()`

```
$('.other a').each(function(){
  var PostURL = this.href;
  $(this).parent().next().load(PostURL + ' .avat img');
});
```

Comment: @Jai Yes, `.next()` element does not exist as to current `this` : `<a>` element at `html`